# Unpack Issue : unpack requires a buffer of 31 bytes

Tags: python

May I know why the following results in as such ?

Code

```
from struct import *
size = 30
sample = bytes(size)
print(sample)
print(len(sample))
body = unpack("10sHBB4sB8sHB", sample)
print(body[0])
```

Result:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
30
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/src/python/sample.py", line 6, in <module>
    body = unpack("10sHBB4sB8sHB", sample)
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 31 bytes
```

Python version : 3.9.2

Comment: i am not sure above threads answer the question posted here, would you explain please ? I am trying to unpack 30 bytes of data with "10sHBB4sB8sHB" but , unpack expects 31 bytes this was my problem.

Comment: Have you tried setting size to 31? Seems your code works when it is 31. Apologies for the above seems I misread.

Comment: 31 works but isn't it incorrect ? because the unpack should expect 30 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format string requires 31 bytes because Python structs use native alignment by default. Therefore, it inserts a padding byte for the second `H` (unsigned short), because otherwise it would end up at an odd offset (27). To avoid padding, you have to disable alignment by preceding the format string with the `=` flag character.

```
>>> from struct import *
>>> calcsize ("10sHBB4sB8sHB")
31
>>> calcsize ("=10sHBB4sB8sHB")
30
```

This is explained in great detail in the [documentation of the struct module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html).